# Description for effective search on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, feature-request, search

I have noticed that it is possible to use some boolean operations (at least with tags) in a search string. Is there a description of how to effectively use search on Stack Overflow?

For example:

- Use [tagName1] **or** [tagname2] to get a conjunction of them
- Look at the *Related* and *Linked* section on the right hand side bar on the right side by your found entries
- etc.).

Comment: For an effective search, use Google... Almost not kidding...

Comment: As veve said, google: `site:stackoverflow.com search terms here`.  That is how I find most of what I need.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, but the question is not "how do I effective search on SO", but "Is there any description for SO". Where do you know it about ´site:stackoverflow.com search terms here.´ from? Have you read it somewhere in some help or description on Google? ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search -> click on "Advanced Search Tips" or https://www.google.de/advanced_search ... both isn't hard to find if you would ... search.

Comment: @Tom: That's it, I have asked for! I have always failed to see "Advanced Search Tips"

Comment: @Rekshino from an UX point of view it would be interesting to know *why* you have always failed to see that link to Advanced Search Tips. Does it need to `<blink>`? Any other suggestion?

Comment: @rene: I don't know. Also as Tom has written, I haven't found it immediately. Usually I type in on the main page and link 'advanced search Tips' becomes visible on results page,where all attention is already on results and the link is to much a side. May be it would be better to put it beneath the edit box.. Blink I find not good :) bold is better..

Comment: @rene - I believe the primary reason would be it isn't visible until the search results are present. The problem being that most people who search immediately move to the results, and only a very small scroll will push you past the link to suggest advanced tips. Moreover, most people tend to look at top:15%, left:15% when a page is loading, which in this case will lead to them reading the first result, looking at the second or third and then scrolling would be the most common route of use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, Tom helps me to find an Answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching